# Showing that a function is continuous for $x$

Tags: continuity

If $f(x)$ is continuous at the point $x=0$ and for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, the function $f(x+y)= f(x) + f(y)$.
Show that $f$ is continuous for all values of $x$.

Not sure where to begin this problem. Any info on it would be appreciated.

Comment: Add some context. What is the domain, what is the range of the function? What is the definition of continuity you're using? Are you familiar with many equivalent definitions?

Answer (score 0):

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$|f(x +h) -f(x)| = \left|\left(f(x) +f(h)\right) -\left(f(x) +f(0)\right)\right| = |f(h) -f(0)| \underset{h \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ since $f$ is continuous at $0$.
This shows that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)$

Thus $f(0)=0$

$$\lim_ {h\to 0} f(x+h)-f(x)=\lim_ {h\to 0} f(h)=f(0)=0$$

Therefore $f(x)$  is continuous at $x$